NSIS uninstaller deleted on reboot
This is a follow up to a previous question.
I am writing an NSIS installer that first checks if the app has already been installed and prompts the user to uninstall before proceeding.
The problem is that (whether or not uninstaller is run silently or otherwise) Windows will delete the previous uninstaller on reboot. And in the case where the previous and current uninstallers have the same name and are installed in the same location Windows will delete the current uninstaller assuming that it is the new one, even if the old uninstaller has been manually deleted as shown below:
; $R0 is the full path to the uninstall application.
ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${APPNAME}" "UninstallString"

; $R1 is the install direction of the exiting installation of App.
ReadRegStr $R1 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${APPNAME}" "InstallLocation"

ExecWait '$R0 /S _?=$R1' ; silent uninstall deletes new installer
;ExecWait '$R0 _?=$R1'  ; non-silent uninstall also deletes the new installer.
Delete $R0 ; manually delete uninstaller

What would the best way to solve this problem? I am considering

Copying the previous uninstaller to the TEMP directory and running it from there, or
Renaming the previous uninstaller before running it.

Update
The install section looks like this:
section "uninstall"
    rmDir /r /REBOOTOK "$SMPROGRAMS\${APPNAME}"
    rmDir /r /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${APPNAME}"
    ; make sure windows knows about the change
    SendMessage ${HWND_BROADCAST} ${WM_WININICHANGE} 0 "STR:Environment" /TIMEOUT=5000
sectionEnd


What does the code in the old uninstaller look like? "Delete /RebootOK"?

@Anders I have added the uninstall section. I guess I need to remove \REBOOTOK from rmDir /r /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR

You are pretty liberal with the /REBOOTOK there. The start menu shortcuts are never going to be locked, you don't need it there. Also, unless you are installing drivers or shell extensions, you don't really need /REBOOTOK at all. Take a look at the DeleteFileOrAskAbort macro in \Examples\install-per-user.nsi, that is often all you need.

Okay. Dropping /REBOOTOK from rmDir /r /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR works -- for the new uninstaller however the old uninstaller (with the same name) still asks for a reboot (because it was built with /REBOOTOK, and arranges for itself to be deleted. Perhaps I need an IF condition that detects the improved installer vs the old one and renames the old uninstaller so that it does not clash with the new.

You best option is to use a different .exe name for the new uninstaller (uninst.exe => uninstaller.exe or vice versa).
If you intend to continue using /REBOOTOK, you might want to create a custom parameter you can pass ("..\old\uninst.exe" /NOREBOOT _?=..\old) and that would make it skip trying to reboot and just do a normal delete instead.
Edit: Another suggestion would be to write a custom uninstaller that installs the old version without rebooting. If they are compatible enough, your current installer could just WriteUninstaller to the old install directory and then run that instead of the original uninstaller.

I've removed /REBOOTOK and I am deleting pending delete-on-reboots instead, i.e. DeleteRegValue  HKLM  "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" "PendingFileRenameOperations". Unfortunately this can clear unrelated pending delete-on-reboots. Unfortunately PendingFileRenameOperations is a multiline string ReadRegStr does not read multiline strings well, or so it seems.

Yes, it is a pain to deal with.

Got any ideas on how to read the reg value?
